# '_csv.reader' object is not callable

Tags: python, csv

This program is supposed to emit sound based on a CSV file.

There is a frequency range in the dataset of 37-32677. In the beginning I didn't add this in and got this same error message. I tried adding in this range and I am still getting the same error.

```
import winsound
import csv

winsound.Beep(261,100)

def preload(filename):
    file = open(filename)
    data = csv.reader(file)
    return data

def getNote(sensorVal):
    return int(sensorVal * 75)

def setup():
    cleanedData = {}
    notes = []
    data = preload("data1.csv")
    for row in data(range(36,32677)):
        print(row)
        if row[1] != "trial number":
            sensorVal = float(row[4])
            channel = int(row[7])
            if channel not in cleanedData:
                cleanedData[channel] = []
            cleanedData[channel].append({"sensorVal":sensorVal})
            notes.append(getNote(sensorVal))
    return cleanedData,notes

def play(notes,time):
    for note in notes:
        winsound.Beep(note,time)

data, notes = setup()
play(notes, 200)
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/clair/PycharmProjects/winSound/main.py", line 32, in <module>
   data, notes = setup()
  File "C:/Users/clair/PycharmProjects/winSound/main.py", line 16, in setup
    for row in data(range(36,32677)):
TypeError: '_csv.reader' object is not callable

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: How about you try adding the separator parameter?

Comment: @G.Anderson `csv.reader` objects are not subscriptable.

Comment: What are you intending to do here? `for row in data(range(36,32677)):`, to iterate over the rows, you simply do `for row in data: ...`

Comment: Sounds like they want to use only some of the rows. Thank you for correcting me on iterability vs subscriptability, the OP should be able to wrap it in a list and slice instead of using the range.

Comment: Unless the input file has multiple comma-separated values on each line, there's no need to read it with `csv.reader()`. What is the format of the data in the file?